# dropdownlist taking another's value

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, query-string

I have two drop down lists on my page, ddlMin and ddlMax.

On page load I have it select the value of a request.querystring. When debugging it take the selected value until it reaches the next line which it then takes IT'S selected value?

http://localhost:37661/Default.aspx?search=&min=450000

```
ddlMin.SelectedValue = !FpsFunctions.IsNothing(Request.QueryString["min"]) 
    ? Request.QueryString["min"] 
    : "0"; <-- at this point it's 450000

ddlMax.SelectedValue = !FpsFunctions.IsNothing(Request.QueryString["max"])
    ? Request.QueryString["max"] 
    : "0"; <-- after this ddlMin.SelecgtedValue changes back to 0
```

I've checked the .cs.designer to make sure it wasn't inheriting something daft but it all seems right.

Cheers for the help in advance.

Comment: public static bool IsNothing(string stringToTest)
        {
            return string.IsNullOrEmpty(stringToTest);
        }

Comment: Could you provide some of your code? And a link to your localhost won't help us.

Comment: The localhost link was just to show the querystring I'm pulling from. Not sure if there's any more code required as when debugging the ddlMin takes the value till the next line and then looses it. What other code would you need to see?

Comment: Now it's clearer with the code snippet you provided.    Try forcing the ddlMin state and use ddlMin.DataBind(); right after setting the selectedValue.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not done anything either. I've been developing in .Net code for well over 8 years now and not seen anything like this before. When you say force the state what do you mean? Like I said before it takes the value after that I've added the ddlMin.DataBind(); but still on the ddlMax.selectedValue change it looses it's value?

Comment: hmmmmm to make things a little more interesting if I alter the ddlMax.SelectedValue it comes back with this error Cannot have multiple items selected in a DropDownList.

Comment: Do you have a _SelectedIndexChanged event on the ddlMin that changes the ddlMax?

Comment: no but I think I've figure it out... I'll stick the answer up now

Comment: oh apparently I can't answer my own question for another 7 hours... I have solved the problem though. It's due to adding a new listitem to both boxes which you can't do. Thanks for you help though.

Comment: You should edit your original post and provide an update. It was obvious enough that we needed more code/markup to help you out as what you posted wasn't enough to go by.

Comment: Okay sure sorry this is first time using the facilities of this site and don't really know how it all works just yet. I've added the answer now. Unfortunately I've not really able to add too much code to this site as I'm under confidentiality agreement with it all. Although saying that just putting where I'd databound the items probably wouldn't have made too much difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating my dropdownlist I was creating my items like so

```
            foreach (string item in ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Budget"].Split(','))
            {
                items = item.ToLower() == "any"
                            ? new ListItem(item, "0")
                            : item.Contains("+")
                                  ? new ListItem(String.Format("{0:0,0}+", Convert.ToInt32(item.Replace("+", ""))),
                                                 "999999999")
                                  : new ListItem(String.Format("{0:0,0}", Convert.ToInt32(item)), item);
                ddlMin.Items.Add(items);
                ddlMax.Items.Add(items);
            }
```

What this meant, although I'm unclear as to why it has so much effect, was that the listitem was being attached to both dropdownlists as a singular item. So even though ddlMin was getting the right value and selecting it when the ddlMax was coming back as 0 it would select the same listitem in both... in order to correct this problem you need to just separate the adding to ddlMin and ddlMax...

```
            foreach (string item in ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Budget"].Split(','))
            {
                items = item.ToLower() == "any"
                            ? new ListItem(item, "0")
                            : item.Contains("+")
                                  ? new ListItem(String.Format("{0:0,0}+", Convert.ToInt32(item.Replace("+", ""))),
                                                 "999999999")
                                  : new ListItem(String.Format("{0:0,0}", Convert.ToInt32(item)), item);
                ddlMin.Items.Add(items);
            }


            foreach (string item in ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Budget"].Split(','))
            {
                items = item.ToLower() == "any"
                            ? new ListItem(item, "0")
                            : item.Contains("+")
                                  ? new ListItem(String.Format("{0:0,0}+", Convert.ToInt32(item.Replace("+", ""))),
                                                 "999999999")
                                  : new ListItem(String.Format("{0:0,0}", Convert.ToInt32(item)), item);

                ddlMax.Items.Add(items);
            }
```

Annoying but necessarily apparently